# What does a ScriptManager script reference do?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms, scriptmanager

On a previous project that I was working on, I noticed that the javascript files were included inside the script manager like so:

```
 <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" />
 <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/site.js" />
```

I've tried searching as to what the difference between a script reference and a regular `<script src="/>` is in an asp page but can't seem to find any information. Is there an advantage to using a script reference?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are using ScriptManager then a single Composite Script can be created to reduce the number of browser requests by ASP.NET.

You can also refer [ScriptReference Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptreference(v=vs.110).aspx)

Also the `about` section of the ScriptManager tells more details about
 it:

> [ScriptManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptreference(v=vs.110).aspx) is an ASP.NET control that manages ASP.NET Ajax
>   script libraries. The ScriptManager performs the following functions.
>
> 1. Enables partial page rendering
> 2. Eanbles client side script access to web services
> 3. Enables use of authenication and profile services from the client
>
> Only one ScriptManager can be allowed per page. For scenarios where a
>   second ScriptManager reference is required, such as within an
>   usercontrol, the [ScriptManagerProxy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanagerproxy.aspx) control should be used.